# How to use php's SHA1 function to generate a list of hash/Base64 outputs?

Tags: php

I want to use PHP's SHA1 function to generate a list of hash/Base64 outputs from a single string.

For example, if I have a string, "ABCDE"

Then I want to generate 5 outputs like:

```
echo sha1('ABCDE');
echo sha1('BCDE');
echo sha1('CDE');
echo sha1('DE');
echo sha1('E');
```

And the number of outputs will match the length of the string. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: `while (strlen($str)) { $str = substr($str, -1); }` would be the loop. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php I'll let you figure out the rest, else it just takes the fun out of it. Edit: Well its wrong, but something like that... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$s = 'ABCDE';
$t = strlen($s);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $t; $i++) {
  echo sha1($s);
  echo '</br>';
  $s = substr($s, 1);
}
?>
```

I use a for loop but you can use `while` too. I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

It was annoying me, this is the easiest by far.

```
$str = 'ABCDE';
while (strlen($str)) {
    echo sha1($str);
    $str = substr($str, 1);
}
```